# Display all data from DB to php page

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all data that are related to each other. 
For example, I have a sales_item table

```
itemid | srfno | qty | serial | description
1      |1234   |1    |354     |laptop
2      |1234   |2    |456     |iphone
```

I want to display the 2 qty, serial and description since they both belong to the same srfno. I can only output the first one. Pls help me.

my select statement to count all the same srfnos

```
Select COUNT(sales_item.srfno) as srfno from sales_item;
```

getting data from db:

```
$exqty=$row['exqty'];
$exserial=$row['exserial'];
$exdesc=$row['exdesc'];
```

I output it using:

```
   <input name=qty  value="<?php echo $exqty ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you issue the following select statement:

```
Select COUNT(sales_item.srfno) as srfno from sales_item;
```

you will get a row array in php like this:

```
Array (
   0 =>  Array (
           "srfno" => 2
   )
)
```

Since the result does not contain any member with the name `exqty` the statement `$row['exqty'];` will end in an error `undefined index "exqty"`.

Either you adjust your Select statement ("`select * from sales_item`") or your php code - depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Besides:

```
    Select COUNT(sales_item.srfno) as srfno from sales_item;
```

will run into problems as your expression `COUNT(sales_item.srfno)` is named the same as the column itself. Better:

```
    Select COUNT(sales_item.srfno) as srfno_count from sales_item;
```

Comment: Undefined index is not an error, just a warning, it says `NOTICE` Though. As a matter of fact its print will be empty

Comment: @Axel Amthor I still got the first data :(

Comment: @Fabio - Notice is what php names it, for me this is an error. Referencing undefined indexes should be handled by proper code - `isset(...)` e.a.

Comment: @ninja3 - you should get at least two rows and you need to iterate over those.